# JavaScript is loading 3 times on Rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, turbolinks

I have an ajax function that is being called multiple times on click when it should just be firing once.

```
$(document).on('click', '.newGameItem', function() {
    console.log('start click event');
    var apiUrl = $(this).attr('data-api-string');
    var callType = $(this).attr('data-api-post-call');
    var apiKey = $(this).attr('data-api-key');
    var dataType = $(this).attr('data-api-data-type');
    var returnValue = $(this).attr('data-return-value');
    var currentGameWrapper = $(this).parent().parent().parent();

    console.log('before api call');
    getNewItem(apiUrl, callType, apiKey, dataType, returnValue, currentGameWrapper);
    console.log('after api call');
});
```

This click event is inside a turbolinks load event:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {  ...  }
```

I put in a console.log at the top of the turbolinks load event and can confirm that the JavaScript in this file is running 3 times. I've noticed this happens when I am on this page, click a link to another page and then hit the back button to this page but it also happens when I click to the page from somewhere else in the app.

This file is being compiled through the asset pipeline and we have `data-no-turbolink` on the body tag (which has actually never seemed to do anything.

Any ideas why this is happening or ways to get around it? Taking turbolinks out of my app completely is not an option for me at this time.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That click event has to be outside the `'turbolinks:load'` event, that's the point of attaching it to `$(document)` as opposed to the element. If you have it inside it will create it every time a page loads. Your javascript should look like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.newGameItem', function() {
  // ...
});

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I also assumed this was the case but it does not work.

Comment: What doesn't work? Is the event triggered more than once? This is definitely how it should be, it shouldn't work if it's defined into the `turbolinks:load`.

Comment: Excuse me, you were correct. It appeared to not be "working" at first because there was a function in the click event that was defined in the turbolinks load event. When I moved that function out of the turbolinks load function, everything worked. Thanks!!